# How to handle millions of records daily with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table in mysql like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `connections` (
  `src` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sport` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dst` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dport` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`src`,`sport`,`dst`,`dport`,`time`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2.5 million records daily inserted in this table.

When i want to select records for a period of time like a day. it takes about 7 minutes.
how can i improve it.

i`m using ruby on rails version 4.0.0

My selection is like this

```
connections = Connection.select('src, dst, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as time')
                  .where(time: timeFrom..timeTo)
                  .order('time ASC')
```

After selection from database i have a loop like this :

```
connections.each do |con|

        link = getServerID(con['src'])
        link = getServerID(con['dst']) if link == 0

        @total[link].append [con['time'] * 1000, con['dst']]
end
```

in this loop i have a bit process on src and dst then i add it to a hash
this sections takes along and my computer crashed

Comment: I need that records, I don`t want to select less records.

Comment: Get more powerful server then

Comment: That looks rather like a single piece of SQL could get your final result without the need to loop around a large amount of data in ruby on rails. Presume you can get the src and / or dst server ids with a join. Post a bit of test data and examples of what you would want output from it.

Comment: This might help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/how-to-speed-up-queries-on-a-large-220-million-rows-table-9-gig-data


and 

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/can-mysql-reasonably-perform-queries-on-billions-of-rows

Comment: There are two things I can think of from a mysql perspective. 1. Why is primary key all fields if you only grab 3 (potentially when you insert, you do not need all 2.5 m records, just unique 3 keys?) 2. Add index for timestamp (unless that is what key statement does?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should try to run the SQL query directly against the database without Rails. This helps to identify the bottleneck: Is the query itself slow or is rails slow? I guess the SQL part should not be a problem, but double check that first.

I guess your biggest problem lies in `connections.each`. This loads all matching rows into your application and creates `ActiveRecord` models of it. Let's do some math: `2.5M entries * 1KB` (just guessing, probably more) would result in `2.5GB` of data loaded into your memory. You may see an improvement in using `connection.find_each` instead, because it loads the connections in smaller batches.

What does `getServerID` method do? It is called `5M` times.

I am pretty sure that you will not be able to improve this code that much. Seems like the wrong database for the problem or a bad algorithm. Since it is unlikely that you want to display `2.5M` records on a website, it is a better idea to tell us what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could try table partitioning:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

There is also a nice slide:

http://www.slideshare.net/datacharmer/mysql-partitions-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, fetching 2.5 mio entries requires loads of memory / cpu power. Try fetching the records in batches.

Rails has batch support build-in: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

```
connections.find_each do |con|
    link = getServerID(con['src'])
    link = getServerID(con['dst']) if link == 0

    @total[link].append [con['time'] * 1000, con['dst']]
end
```

If that's not solving your problem, you should consider finding a better way to not loop through such an amount of records each time.